# Align Text in Middle of Grid box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I vertically align text in the middle of a box? This does not center text in vertical middle. see red arrow below.

```css
.grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 140px 140px;
        grid-template-rows: 140px;
        align-items: stretch;
    }

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.test
{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="gridid42f08d611e2346748fbe47264fd732e0">
    <img class="imgcard mCS_img_loaded" id="imgid42f08d611e2346748fbe47264fd732e00" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image">
    <div class="test"> test </div>
</div>
```

[image]

test

Comment: [mcve]!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Rob apologize issue with editor. just fixed. thanks. feel free to rethumbs up question

Comment: what about `align-items: center` on `.grid-container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [`align-self: center;`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-align-self) on the child? (see also [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self#Values))

That is:

```
.test {
  align-self: center;
}
```

Here's your example, but with that extra property:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 140px 140px;
  grid-template-rows: 140px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.test {
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container" id="gridid42f08d611e2346748fbe47264fd732e0">
    <img class="imgcard mCS_img_loaded" id="imgid42f08d611e2346748fbe47264fd732e00" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image">
    <div class="test"> test </div>
</div>
```

As a sidenote, in your question you have `vertical-align: center`, which is incorrect; the `vertical-align` property takes [`middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Values_for_inline_elements) instead (for whatever bizarre reason)

Comment: thanks it works!  one more quick question,  what if wanted to center the word title on top,and description in middle of the same right cell?